# Retain one tween out of many in one function (TweenMax JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

Im working on a site that requires the "3D card flip effect." I'm already using TweenMax to animate certain graphics on the site so I figured I would use TweenMax for the 3D card flip.

I have this. Basically it scales up and rotates on the hover state. I want it to scale up, rotate and scale down while retaining the `rotationY` property. Any ideas how to do this?

```
$('#selector').on('mouseover', cardFlip).on('mouseout', cardFlipBack);

function cardFlip(e) {
    var tar = $(e.currentTarget);
    $(e.currentTarget).css("z-index", "210");
    TweenMax.to(tar, 0.25, {css: {scale: 1.5, rotationY: -180}});
}

function cardFlipBack(e) {
    var tar = $(e.currentTarget);
    TweenMax.to(tar, 0.25, {css: {scale: 1, rotationY: 0}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! When you hover over the image it scales down and up when you 'mouseout.' When you click on the object the card scales up, flips 180 degrees and stays there until you click it again, then it reverts back to its original degree and scale.

```
var cardFlipClick = false;

$('#include-why').on('mouseover', hoverin).on('mouseout', hoverout).on('click', cardFlip);

function cardFlip(e) { // MAKES CARD FLIP WORK
    if('click') {
        if (!cardFlipClick) {
            console.log('flipCard1 CLICKED!');
            var card = $(e.currentTarget).off('mouseout').off('mouseover').css("z-index", "210");
            TweenMax.to(card, 0.4, {css: {rotationY: -180, scale: 1.5}});
            cardFlipClick = true;
        } else if (cardFlipClick) {
            var card = $(e.currentTarget).on('mouseout', hoverout).on('mouseover', hoverin);
            console.log('flipCard2 CLICKED!');
            TweenMax.to(card, 0.4, {css: {rotationY: 0, scale: 1}});
            cardFlipClick = false;
            }
        }
    }
```